# What is a sampling procedure for $T(X)$ given the sampling procedure for $X$ where $T$ is a deterministic map?

Tags: random-variables, sampling

Given $X$ is a random variable and $Y = T(X)$ where $T$ is a deterministic function, then, $Y$ is a random variable. Consider the following sampling procedure: sample $x \sim X$, then apply $T$ on $x$ to get $T(x)$. Is this sampling procedure guaranteed to be that for sampling from $Y = T(X)$?

This question could be trivial (because it is intuitively correct that the sampling procedure above is indeed for $Y$) but I could not either find a counter-example against that or find some text that explicitly claims that.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $T(x)$ follows the distribution of $Y$ by definition.

Comment: @angryavian Do you have any pointer to that definition?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you and angryavian that the statement is trivially correct, since for every $A$ in the considered $\sigma$-algebra we have
$$
P(T(x)\in A) \stackrel{x\sim X}{=} P(T(X)\in A) = P(Y\in A).
$$